# Missing expression error in application used to submit SQL but when works fine in SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

When I wrote the code below in Oracle SQL Developer it works fine, when pasting this code into Webwise a tool we use to create reports, it errors saying missing experession? We usually just copy and paste the code and it works fine...

**Code is :**

```
select o.wh_id, 
       o.bill_to_code,
       (case when d.pick_area like 'GPS%' then 'GPS' 
             else d.pick_area
       end) as pick_area,
       count(*) as OUC
  from t_order o 
       INNER JOIN
       t_pick_detail d
         on o.order_number = d.order_number
 where o.wh_id = '~wh_id~'
group by o.wh_id, 
         o.bill_to_code,
         (case when d.pick_area like 'GPS%' then 'GPS' 
               else d.pick_area
         end)
order by o.bill_to_code;
```

Comment: Don't know Webwise, but does it have a special meaning for '~' that causes an issue?

Comment: we have created a search field called wh_id and for all previous reports I have done it wont work with out them, so I cant imagine that is the issue.

Comment: Have you tried removing the ';' ?

Comment: May be the statement is too long for the text field and it gets cut? Did you consider the current date ... ? ;) What is the underlying technique (JDBC, dynamic SQL)? How is the terminator defined for the sessions?

Comment: removing the ; worked thanks Frank

Comment: Perhaps try to loose the semi colon in the end?

Answer (score 1):

To finalize this post, Remove the ';' to ensure it works.

As an added note.  The underlying mechanism that actually runs your SQL may have a different interpreter and in some cases, this will cause issues.  When dealing with various tools that interact with the same platform, ensure syntax is correct per the documentation of that system.

Answer (score 0):

When you copy paste code, make sure to check your "" and '' - many a times, the inverted commas get messed up